# Compare two date in objectiveC?

Tags: iphone, ios, comparison, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two date like currentdate and getDate, I want to compare getdate is old or new or equal.

I tried this for your reference:

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *currentDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]; 
    // Current_date (7/26/2013)

    NSString *getdate=[outDateformatter1 stringFromDate:bDt1]; 
   // Get_date (7/26/2010)

    NSComparisonResult result;        
    result = [currentDate compare:getdate]; // comparing two dates
    if(result==NSOrderedAscending)
        NSLog(@"today is less");

  I need this, Original result getdate is old date.
```

But its not working properly, please any one suggest me for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Refere this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901061/comparing-two-dates-with-nsdate?rq=1

Comment: When you compare dates, compare the NSDate objects not strings you create from them, and use isEqualToDate:.

Comment: Compare date objects not the strings.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper see my answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758253/how-to-compare-two-dates-and-time-in-iphone-sdk/13758280#13758280 and also USe `NSDate` instead of `NSString` for `compare:` method

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate *serDate;

    NSDate *endDate;

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    serDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 7:17:58"];

    endDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 08:43:30"];
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:serDate];

    double minutes = timeDifference / 60;

    double hours = minutes / 60;

    double seconds = timeDifference;

    double days = minutes / 1440;
    NSLog(@" days = %.0f,hours = %.2f, minutes = %.0f,seconds = %.0f", days, hours, minutes, seconds);


    if (hours > 1.30)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
```

Comment: Actually getdate is not constant value.

Comment: endDate = [formatter dateFromString:getdate];

Answer (score 0):

Use `compare` method.

```
if ([currentdate compare: getDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"currentdate is later than getDate");        

} else if ([currentdate compare:getDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"currentdate is earlier than getDate");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this function to compare current date to another date  

 - (NSInteger)numberOfDaysUntil:(NSDate *)aDate {
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:aDate options:0];

    //NSLog(@"Number of days  >>>%d",[components day]);

    return [components day];

// then use this logic 

 if ([self numberOfDaysUntil:date]==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Today");
    }
    else if ([self numberOfDaysUntil:date]== -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Yesterday");
    }
    else{

        // if return is -2 then date is two date before current date .

// if return is 1 then date is one future date than current day

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for that you have to import NSDate-Utilities.h and .m file.
```

NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

```
float oldDate = [[df dateFromString:[dic valueForKey:@"end_date"]] timeIntervalSinceNow];

 if (oldDate < 0) {
     //past date
}
else if (oldDate > 0){
    //future date
}
else{
    //same date
}
```